# Error when validating xml schema

Tags: xml, schema

I want to make a simple schema for an empty elment

```
 <product orderid="4"/>
```

I created my XSD like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/first"
xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/first"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:element name="product" type="prodtype"/>
<xsd:complexType name="prodtype">
        <xsd:attribute name="prodid" type="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

I get the following error when validating the XML against the XSD:

```
 Error resolving component 'prodtype'. It was detected that 'prodtype' has no namespace, but components with no target namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/D:/Teacher%20assistant%202011/First%20term/web%20services/test%20programs/BpelModule1/src/product.xsd'. If 'prodtype' is intended to have a namespace, perhaps a prefix needs to be provided. If it is intended that 'prodtype' has no namespace, then an 'import' without a "namespace" attribute should be added to 'file:/D:/Teacher%20assistant%202011/First%20term/web%20services/test%20programs/BpelModule1/src/product.xsd'.
```

Comment: btw, `xsd:schema` is not closed in your above code, could that be related?

Comment: No, it's just error in formating, this code works with me but after removing "tns" from xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/first", I didn't understand the reason till now !

Answer (score 12):

This will work, adding 'tns:' to the type.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/first"
    xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/first"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">    
    <xsd:element name="product" type="tns:prodtype"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="prodtype">
        <xsd:attribute name="prodid" type="xsd:integer"/>
    </xsd:complexType>    
</xsd:schema>
```

The prodtype is defined in the targetNamespace of the schema in this case 'http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/first'. In order to reference it you need to include the namespace that is is defined in. In your example to are trying to reference a prodtype in the default namespace which is not defined.

Answer (score 6):

If you change your XSD and put `xmlns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/first"` in `xsd:schema` element it should work (it did for me)

Comment: Excellent answer, complimentary to that of @jeremyhare.